# Power BI - Azure SQL DB connection issue

Tags: authentication, powerbi, azure-sql-database

When I am trying to get data from "Azure SQL DB" in Power BI, I am unable to complete the authentication. After I have entered server name & database name, I will go to the Microsoft account option to login with the credentials provided, but instead of asking me for the password, it logs me in with the current credentials of power bi environment (which are not authorised). So I need to know what can I do to login here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a generic issue, what you are seeing is auto signin to already signed in account. You can either logout of all existing accounts in the browser or use new private browser window to login clearing all cached and active logins from the privacy properties.

Comment: Actually I am facing this issue on power bi desktop & have already logged out from all accounts.

Comment: So I am marking the above answer as correct as this is somewhat on the lines of what I found for my issue, it was auto signing but to fix it I had to change custom level security of Local Intranet in Internet options, I set it to prompt for username & password & it worked.